# Does Zombie mode in Black Ops ever end?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I have a friend who seems very convinced that Black Ops zombies simply "never ends," and that it can't be completed or won.

Certainly, the maps cannot continue onto infinity, as these maps would have to exist, and hence have been designed, correct?

Comment: I think your asking the wrong question. Black Ops zombie maps don't continue on forever as they are defined maps. According to the game it does not end because zombies continue to spawn stronger and in more numbers as you progress through rounds. The correct question isn't talking about the maps, but the Zombies Spawning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps do not keep going as they are defined. 
[image]

Such as the image above. However, zombies endlessly spawn which causes the game to go on until you die or quit. However, multi-player scoreboards don't seem to be able to score anything over 99.

So to answer your question, **yes**, zombies go on forever but the maps do not.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

> [No, it doesn't end](http://segmentnext.com/2010/12/11/call-of-duty-black-ops-zombies-strategy-guide/).  The difficulty keeps going up (number of zombies spawned, etc.).  Presumably with some limit, though.

You're right that the maps don't keep going, although it is technically possible for maps to be generated on the fly.  (Think *Worms*, but more complicated).

Answer (score -3):

It never ends! ZOMBIES GET STRONGER EVERY ROUND!
The highest round I reached is 146, where dogs and flying zombies come! dogs are explosive dogs!you just have to survive as long as you can.