# Is there a max round on Black Ops: Nazi Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I understand that zombies endlessly spawn. However, scoreboards seem only to register to round 99. Does this mean that there is a glitch where you die at round 99? Or is it simply a issue where the scoreboards can't record anything over 99?

Comment: Duplicate http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/does-black-ops-zombies-ever-end

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I asked a different question.

Comment: " However, zombies endlessly spawn which causes the game to go on until you die or quit. However, multi-player scoreboards don't seem to be able to score anything over 99.

So to answer your question, yes, zombies go on forever but the maps do not."

Comment: I am not sure of that response so I am asking if it is true that the scoreboards can't simply register over 99.

Comment: **scoreboards don't seem to be able to score anything over 99.**

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I am VERIFYING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no end to the zombie mode, and people have been to [at least level 100](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms19lgoFvus).  I would wager that most people who have made it past round 99 glitched or cheated though (like the guy in the video), as the difficulty at such a high level is nigh impossible, and it would take an entire day or more of dedicated playing to get this far.

The leaderboards weren't really designed for this kind of play, so it is highly likely that the max level they can display is 99, and that the people at the top glitched to get there.

Comment: It is very possible to get to that level without glitching... I just got bored. I got as far as level 88 solo... no glitch, no hack.

Comment: Thus the "most people" in my answer.  If you're dedicated, I'm sure you can get that far.

Answer (score 0):

It's just unable to register higher than 99. The user *TheSyndicateProject* made it to round 116, then another player made it to round 136. My highest is round 36, but I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I have been to round 147 and I was just fine, but the reason for this is because there is automatic target finder (so you aim for the zombies and makes aiming easier).  I also did it tactical, was smart about my moves, trained a lot, and with monkeys and the crossbow upgraded it attracts the zombies and kills them or makes a crawler.

Answer (score 0):

My Highest level is 2099. There's no Limit's. The game just continues Over and Over again. Never finishes.

Answer (score -3):

There are 2,147,483,647 rounds in zombies because the data type for the rounds on zombies is a 32 bit signed integer so there can't be an infinite number of rounds.

Comment: What proof do you have of this?

Comment: Look on the call of duty wiki or mod the round up to max round